# Searchresults on same page or on 'searchresults.php'

Tags: website-design, search, html, search-results

What is the best way for searching on a webpage.
Should i show the searchresults on a new page or on the same page? (maybe with autocomplete).

I personally like searchresults on the same page as my searchbox. But I wonder of more people share my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Results can be shown on the same page as search criteria or a separate page. This is not an UX item. This is to be decided based on the design convenience. It should be transparent to user whether results are shown on same page or different page.

The real important UX item to note is, if the search results are shown in separate page, the search criteria that is given by user in the first page should be repeated (for display purpose) in the results page also.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the requirement..

1. if your website/product is a search engine (Google, Bing etc) or email (Gmail, Hotmail etc), showing search results on the same page would be a good idea..
2. if you have a website/product where user would be able to search multiple items/products, displaying search results on a new page would be ideal. User should be able to see filters/options related to his/her search query on the results page.

Comment: good catch. they should be able to limit the results by filtering. and indeed that would be easier on a seperate page.